# Create a timeOut class in java

Tags: java, twitter, timeout

I would like to create a java class (thread) that pings twitter and if there is no connectivity wait until there is connection and re-run some  other classes and threads. 
I have the code that "pings" websites and a way to run every static method is in my Main class. Is this a good solution to the problem?

Here is the basic part of the code:

```
while (true){
 try {
final URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.connect();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   Thread.sleep(10000*t);
 if    (url.matches(twitter1)){
        Thread method1= new Thread(Class1.method1);
        method1.start();
 }else if (url.matches(twitter2)){
        Thread method2 = new Thread(Class1.method2);
        method2.start();
}else if (url.matches(twitter3)){
        Main.StaticMethod();
}else if (url.matches(twitter4)){
        Main.StaticMethod2();
}else if (url.matches(twitter5)){
        Main.StaticMethod3();
}else{
        System.out.println("Unknown URL");
}
t=2^t;
}
}
```

Comment: [Use a timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You do not run *classes* or *threads*, you can only *invoke methods*. If the methods are `instance methods` then you need some `object`; otherwise they are `static` and you need to know the `class` in which they are defined. If you want to start another `thread`, then you need an `object` of a `class` that `implements Runnable`.

For example,

```
try {
  final URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
  connection.connect();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  // connection is available, either use it or close it. then,

  // AfterConnect is a class that implements Runnable. Perhaps it takes 
  // the connection as parameter? 
  AfterConnect afterConnect = new AfterConnect(..);

 // this will start a new thread 
  new Thread(afterConnect).start();
```

BTW your example does not "wait until there is connection". If you are going to put the `try...catch` in a loop, you should `sleep` for some time between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

How will you define "running" the classes ? One way to do it would be to store references to these classes in your timeOut class, and then to invoke the methods that you want when you successfully ping the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you have structured the "re-run some other classes and threads" stuff.  If it is in a mishmash of method calls, then you could put the code you presented in an abstract class, and add an abstract method

```
abstract class AbstractTimeout {
   ...  your code here, but add a call to afterConnection() ...

   protected abstract void afterConnection();
}
```

A subclass would implement that by setting up some fields for all the classes objects and calls in a constructor, then implementing the mishmash of calls in

```
protected void afterConnection() {
   class1.goDoThis();
   object2.goDoThat();
   someRunnable.run();
   // ... etc... 
}
```

This is classic `inheritance`.  BTW, you need to consider what Exceptions might be thrown and which to declare.  For simplicity, I ignored that issue.

Alternatively, if the "re-run some other classes and threads" stuff is already in something fairly simple and well organized like a `Runnable`, you could have your class take a `Runnable` along with the `URLConnection` as an argument, and run() the Runnable (or launch it in a new thread) after the connection is complete.  This is classic *composition*.  e.g.

```
public void doTimeout(URL url, Runnable afterConnection) {
      // your connection stuff from above

      afterConnection.run();
   }
```

NOTE : I didn't put afterConnection.run() into a Thread, cause I think that doTimeout should already be in it's own thread.  YMMV.

NOTE2: My 2nd solution is similar to @Miserable Variable afterConnect() concept.  I used a Runnable, he used a a more flexible interface.